# Reading from internal storage (deserialization)

Tags: java, android, android-listview, arraylist

I am using the following method to read from the internal storage:

```
private void deserialize(ArrayList<Alias>arrayList) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        arrayList = (ArrayList<Alias>)ois.readObject();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It reads the content of the file "filename" to the "arrayList".

The "serialize" method is as follows:

```
void serialize(ArrayList<Alias>arrayList) {
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(arrayList);
        oos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is that I whenever I run my program again, the "arrayList" is empty. So I guess I am opening the file in wrong input mode.

My aim is to first get the array from the file, then modify it within the app, and then write the modified array back to the file.

Can someone please help me with my problem?

Thanks!

Comment: is `Alias` serializable?

Comment: @zapl Alias is a very primitive class and it only consists of two "Strings" as its members.

Comment: @zapl Is something special needed to be done to make "Alias" serializable?

Comment: It must at least implement `Serializable` or you should get errors during serialization. http://www.javabeginner.com/uncategorized/java-serialization

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your pice of your source code? I think the way which you used to parse file content get issue.

Answer (score 0):

Read here:

[Android ObjectInputStream docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject%28%29)

I read that the method readObject() read the next object...i this that you must iterate with something like this:

```
MediaLibrary obj = null;
while ((obj = (MediaLibrary)objIn.readObject()) != null) {
    libraryFromDisk.add(obj);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do that if you know that you have stored exactly 1 object.

Comment: (ArrayList<Alias>)ois.readObject() when i read this i think that he expects more than one object...

Comment: 1 entire `ArrayList` object (including it's entries). The code to write also does just 1 `oos.writeObject(someObject)` so the inverse operation is a single `ois.readObject()`.